# How to add US State NHGIS historical GIS data to PostGIS? ERROR: INSERT has more target columns than expressions

Tags: postgis, windows-10, shp2pgsql, bat, postgresql-13

I am trying to add historical data extracted from NHGIS to PostGIS, but I get the ***INSERT has more target columns than expressions*** error when I run the code below:

```
"C:\psql.exe" -c "SELECT loader_load_staged_data(lower('state'), lower('state_all')); "
NOTICE:  INSERT INTO tiger_data.state_all(aland,awater,division,funcstat,intptlat,intptlon,lsad,mtfcc,name,region,statefp,statens,stusps,the_geom) SELECT gisjoin,gisjoin2,icpsrst,nhgisst,shape_area,shape_len,statenam,the_geom FROM tiger_staging.state;
ERROR:  INSERT has more target columns than expressions
LINE 1: ...er,division,funcstat,intptlat,intptlon,lsad,mtfcc,name,regio...
```

With the same command, I was able to add the 2019 Tiger data from the Census site (https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2019/STATE/).

After comparing the 2019 State's dbf from the Census site with the 1930 State's dbf from NHGIS, is obvious the problem is that columns are different.

**Census' State Tiger 2019 dbf**

[image: 2019 States' Tiger Census dbf]

VS

**NHGIS' States 1930 dbf (based on 2000 TIGER/Line +)**

[image: NHGIS 1930 US States dbf]

This is the shp2pgsql output.

```
"C:\shp2pgsql.exe" -D -c -s 4269 -g the_geom   -W "latin1" US_state_1930.dbf tiger_staging.state   | "C:\psql.exe"
Field shape_area is an FTDouble with width 19 and precision 11
Field shape_len is an FTDouble with width 19 and precision 11
Shapefile type: Polygon
Postgis type: MULTIPOLYGON[2]
SET
SET
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
                        addgeometrycolumn
------------------------------------------------------------------
 tiger_staging.state.the_geom SRID:4269 TYPE:MULTIPOLYGON DIMS:2
(1 row)

COPY 51
COMMIT
ANALYZE
```

This is the whole code I run inside a bat file:

```
set YEAR=1930
set DATAFILE="C:\NHGIS\%YEAR%"
set PGBIN="C:\pgsql\bin\"
set PSQL="C:\psql.exe"
set SHP2PGSQL="C:\shp2pgsql.exe"
%PSQL% -c "DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS tiger_staging CASCADE;"
%PSQL% -c "CREATE SCHEMA tiger_staging;"
%PSQL% -c "DO language 'plpgsql' $$ BEGIN IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name = 'tiger_data' ) THEN CREATE SCHEMA tiger_data; END IF;  END $$"
tar.exe -x -f nhgis0002_shapefile_tl2000_us_state_%YEAR%.zip
%PSQL% -c "CREATE TABLE tiger_data.state_all(CONSTRAINT pk_state_all PRIMARY KEY (statefp),CONSTRAINT uidx_state_all_stusps  UNIQUE (stusps), CONSTRAINT uidx_state_all_gid UNIQUE (gid) ) INHERITS(tiger.state); "
%SHP2PGSQL% -D -c -s 4269 -g the_geom   -W "latin1" US_state_%YEAR%.dbf tiger_staging.state | %PSQL%
%PSQL% -c "SELECT loader_load_staged_data(lower('state'), lower('state_all')); "
    %PSQL% -c "CREATE INDEX tiger_data_state_all_the_geom_gist ON tiger_data.state_all USING gist(the_geom);"
    %PSQL% -c "VACUUM ANALYZE tiger_data.state_all"
```

I guess my question then is, **how do I change the columns in PostGIS to match the NHGIS file?** or **How can I make the existing table match the shapefile using SHP2PGSQL?**

I have a hunch that my issue is related to the SRID: 4269 I am providing when running the shp2pgsql command. If that is the issue, then how to identify which SRID should be used?

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing at all to do with your SRID.

You are attempting to use this SQL:

```
INSERT INTO tiger_data.state_all(
 aland, awater, division, funcstat, intptlat, intptlon, lsad, mtfcc, name, region, statefp, statens, stusps, the_geom) 
SELECT gisjoin, gisjoin2, icpsrst, nhgisst, shape_area, shape_len, statenam, the_geom 
FROM tiger_staging.state;
```

So you are trying to insert 13 columns from a table with 8 columns, so Postgresql is confused.

You need to create a table that looks like your historical data and import it into that.

Comment: The problem is that I am not adding the "INSERT INTO...", that is something done by SHP2PGSQL. I added the whole code that I use so you can see what data I am providing. Thank you.

Comment: You are trying to add a shapefile to an existing table that is the wrong width

Comment: I already knew that, my question is how can I make the existing table match the shapefile using SHP2PGSQL.

Comment: You can't - make a new table and then copy the bits you need from both tables in to a new one that is correct.